# error on my package run in Opencpu server

Tags: r, opencpu

I have a package 'soilreports' built in RStudio, and following the sound advice on https://r-pkgs.org/. The package produces the appropriate reports as pdfs in the expected folder. It uses the .Rmd file and applies the params.

When I install it in the /usr/local/lib/R/site-library (and restart apache2) to make it accessible by the opencpu server, it is available via the test page on my server, but it fails to run properly when I supply the params by POST.

The test page returns the error message *"cannot open the connection
In call:
file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))"*.

I interpreted the error as saying that the function cannot write to the working directory. To that directory added a group which contains the right user as I understand it and gave it write permission.

This has not solved it. In the test page when calling "../library/soilreports/R/pointreportgen" with the appropriate params and values, it still produces the error.

Despite much good advice, I am still missing something.
I would greatly appreciate advice to interpret the error message and resolve the problem.

thanks
David

Comment: I'm no expert, but there are major differences between running an app *locally* and running it on a *server*, even if the server is a local server.  Servers usually only have access to the users downloads folder.  Does the app work when deployed and output is directed to the downlaods folder?

Comment: I will have a look at that option. The advice from the opencpu answers in other places is that it should be set to the working directory, using getwd(). I set the working directory from a separate directory outside a user's home, to the top level of the R package, then rebuilt it. Still runs successfully in RStudio but doesn't in the local opencpu server (a site under Apache2).

Comment: Further investigation revealed the OpenCPU author had commented on this kind of issue and recommended checking kern.log

the kern.log contains multiple examples of alerts from the app running on the server:
audit: type=1400 audit(1643794131.233:33): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="opencpu-exec" name="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/soilreports/rmd/{$my file}" pid=16722 comm="apache2" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=33 ouid=33

Comment: From that error it looks like your application is trying to modify or create a file in the installation folder `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/soilreports/rmd` ? How are you invoking this? Try copying that file to the workding directory first and running it from there.

Comment: Hi Jeroen
Thanks for your kind assistance. Solving this is such a high priority for the business that I have been seeking a contractor to assist. So far my search has not been successful.
It was indeed installed there. I copied that folder to the /usr/lib/opencpu/library/ folder and restarted Apache. It now shows in the list of packages when I use the testing server.

Comment: Hi @JeroenOoms
(continuing from above wjere I confirm that I copied the folder to /usr/lib/opencpu/library/ )
I added the params to the function call on the testing server and did the POST. This prompted the function to start, but it failed to complete, as I can see from the stdout file. 
What I read at the warnings file in the /tmp/$output folder is:  _ 'cannot open file 'point_soil_sample_report_params.knit.md': Permission denied'_
Happy to provide more specific details

Comment: Hi @JeroenOoms
I should add that my function sets the $output dir as getwd(). I may have misunderstood the documentation. 
None the less, the machine seems to be saying that it gets to the .md output but cannot get to .pdf stage.

Comment: Can you pls update your post and include some code of the function that you are invoking via opencpu?

Comment: Hi @JeroenOoms,
Here is one of the functions in full

#'@export
pointreportgen <- function(sample_point_id,survey_id, farm_id){xfun::Rscript_call(
  rmarkdown::render(
    input = system.file("rmd", "point_soil_sample_report_params.Rmd", package = "soilreports"),
    output_file = 'Point_Soil_Sample_Report.pdf',
    output_dir = getwd(),
    params = list(sample_point_id = sample_point_id, survey_id = survey_id, farm_id = farm_id)))
}

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the file to your current working directory and then invoking it.

```
pointreportgen <- function(sample_point_id,survey_id, farm_id){
  rmdfile <- system.file("rmd", "point_soil_sample_report_params.Rmd", package = "soilreports")
  file.copy(rmdfile, "input.rmd")
  rmarkdown::render(input = "input.rmd", output_file = 'Point_Soil_Sample_Report.pdf', params = list(
    sample_point_id = sample_point_id, 
    survey_id = survey_id, 
    farm_id = farm_id
  )) 
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeroen
I made those changes and updated the package on the server.
Then I ran:   curl https://soil-health.com.au/ocpu/library/soilreports/R/pointreportgen -d "sample_point_id=72&survey_id=11&farm_id=1"

The server responded:   No root directory found in /tmp/ocpu-temp/x004a3c8a474e35/workspace or its parent directories. Root criterion: contains a file "DESCRIPTION" with contents matching "^Package: "

If you check, you will see that OCPU server generated that DESCRIPTION file. The input.rmd is in the files folder as well.

It looks like progress...

Comment: I very much appreciate your assistance. It feels like we are nearly there.

Comment: Oops. Sorry @JeroenOoms
The call should be
curl https://soil-health.com.au/ocpu/library/soilreports/R/pointreportgen -d "sample_point_id=75&survey_id=11&farm_id=1"

Comment: Hi @JeroenOoms
I found I needed to copy DESCRIPTION to ../DESCRIPTION.
After that some tinytex debugging led me to success!
Thanks again for your guidance. It was essential.